# Javascript: move elements in an array but based on another array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, move

Here's what i'm trying to do. I have an Array arr with strickly 4 elements. can't have more and can't have less. I have another Array called shiftAmounts.
So here's what I have and the result i'm looking for...

`arr[A, B, C, D]`
`shiftAmounts[0, 1, 1, 3]`
`result:  arr[A,"Empty", B, C]`

So starting from the right (the fouth elements) it<s important, I have to move the D to the right by 3 space. Since I can't have more than 4 elements, then it's deleted
Next the C move one space to the right
Next the B move one space to the right
Next the A don't move cause it has 0.
Elements never cross each others.
The change has to be in place.
tks for your help
Seby

Comment: no, really the word Empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made a function for you which can achieve you desired outcome

```js
function shiftArray(arr, shiftAmounts) {
  for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    const shift = shiftAmounts[i];
    if (shift === 0) continue;

    const newIndex = i + shift;
    if (newIndex >= 4) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      continue;
    }

    arr[newIndex] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = "Empty";
  }
  return arr;
}

const arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const shiftAmounts = [0, 1, 1, 3];
const result = shiftArray(arr, shiftAmounts);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very good, thanks you, the only problem that I see is that if I use a [3,3,3,3] or [4,4,4,4], then I get undifined instead of empty. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Map each element of the array to a list of elements and new positions.

Then, use `Object.fromEntries` to treat that array as a list of key-value pairs and create an object from them, and use `Array.from` to convert that into an array. Note that `Array.from` will automatically exclude elements in positions greater than the specified array length.

The second parameter to `Array.from` is an arrow function that replaces missing array elements with the string 'Empty'.

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
const shiftAmounts = [0, 1, 1, 3]

const r = Array.from({
  length: arr.length,
  ...Object.fromEntries(arr.map((e,i) => [i+shiftAmounts[i], e]))
}, e => e ?? 'Empty')

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Hi, tks, how to use this as a function?

Comment: @seby Just declare a `function shiftArr(arr, shiftAmounts) {   }` and put my code followed by `return r` inside